# Apache - How to map a domain to specific path of another domain on the same host?

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, virtualhost

I have a Wordpress website on an address such as `example.com` and there are a few pages like `example.com/shop` , `example.com/products/sample-product` which I want to be viewed via `myshopdotcom.example`, `myshopdotcom.example/products/sample-product` respectively.

I know writing a simple 301 redirect will do the job but I do not want to create a new Wordpress site for `myshopdotcom.example` instead I would like to simply map specific pages from `example.com` to `myshopdotcom.example`.

Is it possible via writing something inside a `VirtualHost`?

Comment: You can use `ServerAlias` in `VirtualHost` to make all pages appear on multiple websites. But that will be too broad if you want only some, but why not the others? If selective, you need two `VirtualHost` and something like `ProxyPass`, besides the DNS being correctly configured of course two point the two names to your server. But you are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

inside the VirtualHost you can use Alias module:

```
<ifModule alias_module>
        Alias "/phpmyadmin" "D:\WebServers\running\phpMyAdmin-4.6.6-english"
        Alias "/mpage1" "F:\folder\for\the\page"
        Alias "/mpage2" "/folder2/page2.html" #in linux
</ifModule>
```

sometimes you should grant access to that file via

```
<Directory "D:\WebServers\running\phpMyAdmin-4.6.6-english">
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```